# SpamAssassin filtering by Exim 4 with virtual user preferences

Tags: email, spam, exim, access-control-list, spamassassin

I would like to configure spam filtering with exim's built-in spam filter support in acl_check_data config section.

The piping, exim header modification (to store result) works well. As well as transporting the mail to Junk folder by dovecot-lda.

My only problem is that I can't pass the virtual user of recipient to spamassassin to let spamd load the user's preferences from sql.

I know, the left side of exim's "spam" keyword is for that, but it does not pass any variable for me. Only static values: simply ignores all variable I set.

Here is my config section:

```
acl_check_data:

  # Deny if the message contains a virus. Before enabling this check, you
  # must install a virus scanner and set the av_scanner option above.
  #
  deny    malware    = *
          message    = This message contains a virus ($malware_name).

  # Add headers to a message if it is judged to be spam. Before enabling this,
  # you must install SpamAssassin. You may also need to set the spamd_address
  # option above.
  # {def:h_Envelope-to:}

        # Accept when mail size is over 500k
  accept  condition = ${if >={$message_size}{500k}{yes}{no}}

  # put headers in all messages (no matter if spam or not)
  warn    spam       = ${local_part}@${domain}:true
          add_header = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score\n\
                       X-Spam-Score-Int: $spam_score_int\n\
                       X-Spam-Level: $spam_bar\n\
                       X-Spam-Report: $spam_report

  # add second subject line with *SPAM* marker when message
  # is over threshold
  warn    message    = Classified as spam.
          spam       = ${local_part}@${domain}
          add_header = X-Spam-Flag: YES\n\
                       Subject: [SPAM] $h_Subject:

  # reject spam at high scores (> 12)
  deny    message    = This message scored $spam_score spam points.
          spam       = ${local_part}@${domain}:true
          condition  = ${if >{$spam_score_int}{120}{true}{false}}

  # Accept the message.

  accept
```

The current form is "${local_part}@${domain}", but I tried more: ${local_part@$domain}, with quotes, without brackets, etc. Only the at sign (@) passed, while variables works at other keywords (conditions for example).

I know, I can make a (resource hungry) transport hook or even filter by dovecot, however I would like to use this feature if possible. So please don't advise other solutions, I know them.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is simply not possible. Checking for spam at SMTP time forbid this as you would end up at somme point scanning one mail (so one single scan) which will contain multiple recipients... Which user preferences would you load then?
In order to do this you need to use a pipe transport (to spamc) at delivery time, not at SMTP time.
In any case, using heavy spam detection (like spamassassin) at SMTP time is a bad idea as it makes your server prone to DoS attacks. Use lighter spam detection at SMTP time and heavy one (with rules that fit each user) at delivery time.

Comment: BTW, I wrote this few years ago. It is probably a bit outdated now, but I believe it may still help: http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-mail-server-using-exim4-clamav-dovecot-spamassassin-and-many-more-on-debian-p2

Comment: Scanning at SMTP time is no more CPU intensive than scanning at delivery time if you always scan.  However, if you want per recipient the scanning must be done at delivery time.  Spamd can be configured to use virtual configuration so should not be a significantly heavier load than scanning at SMTP time.

Comment: Yes and no, of course scanning is scanning and has to be done at some point. But doing it at smtp time will make SMTP sessions *a lot longer* thus making it very easy to starve from connections/memory... Doing the same scan at delivery time makes it possible to rely on earlier lightweight spam detection (possibly at smtp time) to drop spam before it even reach the delivery agent, saving resources on both the smtp and the delivery host.

Comment: @axgomz I use delays starting at connect time for hosts failing reverse DNS validation, or listed in selected blacklists.  Very little spam actually makes it to the DATA stage.

Comment: @BillThor if your hosts doesn't handle big mail traffic that's probably more acceptable. However remember that you are not only scanning spam emails but ham as well. No matter how much spam is stopped, the pb lies in the fact to use heavy scan at SMTP time. Why do you want to do that? I guess because you want to fast reject mails. That's a good reason, but only only if you're 100% sure you have to reject that mail, and with spam detection engines you're never sure. At least rbl, greylisting and similar have a predictable behaviour.

Comment: If you scan after accepting, then you are likely to create backscatter spam.  I had to implement BATV to deal with the volume ofbackscatter scam I was receiving.  Also, unless you forward to another server for scanning, the load will be the same, or higher if you scan by recipient.  It is possible to identify a fair amount of ham and not scan it.

Comment: That was exactly my previous point. You should not drop email based on detection services like spamassassin, there are always false positives with this kind of tools. And it's far bigger pb to drop legitimate emails than toconsume extra cpu or even to deliver spam. Mails detected as spam should be deliveredto the junk mailbox, which should be vleaned on a regular basis. Doing so you cant become a backscatter source, you can provide more efficient scanning by using per user rules

Comment: I block (effectively discard) email with high spam scores.  Spam with lower scores gets marked and delivered, as does Bacon.  I've been capturing the blocked email for examination, and none of it is legitimate.  I do have senders who's configuration is so spammish (amaturish) that I have to whitelist it, but there are few of these, and I attempt to provide feedback.

Comment: Yes, thats need multiple scans in case of multiple local recipients. But that's not relevant, you need do this wherever you do the spam filtering. To prevent DoS attacks you need other checks in any way. These should be placed before the spam check of course. If your DoS prevention not work, it doesn't matter where you filter spam... That's my opinion.

Comment: alxgomz: You guide worked. Basically that moves the spam checking from acl checks to router section. That's fine.